# React form sending empty object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to send user input in a form component to the component managing the state. I tried to use a callback but my input is not being sent.

Tried to use the form object in a callback

```
//here is the form component

class ListForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      NewItem: {
        itemText: "",
        id: Date.now(),
        completed: false
      }
    };
  }

  handleChanges = e => {
    this.setState({...this.state,
      NewItem: { ...this.state.NewItem, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }
    });
  };

  submitItem = e => {
     this.setState({ itemText: "" });
    this.props.addItem(e, this.state.NewItem);

  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.submitItem}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.NewItem.itemText}
          name="itemText"
          onChange={this.handleChanges}
        />
        <button>Add</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default ListForm;
```

```
addItem is in the parent component and looks like this. Groceries is just an array of objects with itemText, id and completed 

addItem = (e, item) => {
    e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      groceries: [...this.state.groceries, item]
    });
  };
```

I can enter in the form, but when I hit enter, nothing is added to the list

Comment: console.log values in handlers, inspect state in react dev tools ... just search what doesn't work properly

Comment: @xadm, thanks!, I can console log what I typed in the addItem function, it is not just added to the array

Comment: parent's state changed? console.log in setState callback?

Comment: no it did not, i think the problem is ```this.setState({
            ...this.state,
      groceries: [...this.state.groceries, item]
    });
  };``` this block

Comment: bad constructor? no super call ? show more code

Answer (score 0):

Very first thing to try is to add e.persist to your addItem() function

```
addItem = (e, item) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.persist()
        this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      groceries: [...this.state.groceries, item]
    });
  };
```

Another option is using redux to save the form data in the Global state and then accessing it in the parent component through redux. Here is an example of what that might look like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as ACTIONS from '../store/actions/actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';



class Form1 extends Component {

  state ={
    value: ''
  }

  handleChange = (event) => (
    this.setState({value: event.target.value})
  )

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.props.input_action_creator(event.target.name.value)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input id="name" onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" />
          <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
        </form>
        <br />
      </div>
    )}
}




function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    input_action_creator: (text) => dispatch(ACTIONS.user_input(text))
  }
}


export default connect(mapDispatchToProps)(Form1);


class Parent extends Component {

  access form data with 

  this.props.user_Text

}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    user_text: state.user_reducer.user_text
  }
}
```

here is a fully funcitoning react-redux project if you are interested

https://github.com/iqbal125/modern-react-app-sample